# Why does my altair mark_text() layer come out blurry/duplicated?

Tags: python, streamlit, altair

I am trying to make heatmaps with text on top. I found a great [tutorial](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks/text.html) from the Altair website was trying to adapt my dataset to tutorial which works fine for me. But when I run it with my own data:

```py
import altair as alt, pandas as pd, numpy as np

quarters = ['2022-Q1', '2022-Q2', '2022-Q3', '2022-Q4', '2023-Q1', '2023-Q2', '2023-Q3', '2023-Q4']
risk_bands = ['A++', 'A+', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'R']
vintages = [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]

cpr = pd.DataFrame({
    'quarter': np.random.choice(quarters, 1000),
    'GEN5_RISK_BAND_CALC': np.random.choice(risk_bands, 1000),
    'VINTAGE_YEAR': np.random.choice(vintages, 1000),
    'cpr': np.random.randint(0, 40, 1000)
})


base = alt.Chart(cpr).mark_rect().encode(
    x=alt.X('quarter:O', axis=(alt.Axis(labelAngle=45))),
    y='VINTAGE_YEAR:O',
)

heatmap = base.mark_rect().encode(
    color=alt.Color(
        'cpr:Q',
        scale=alt.Scale(
            # domain=[0, 20, 40],
            range=['white', 'red'],
            # interpolate=method
            ),
        legend=alt.Legend(direction='vertical', orient='left', title='cpr')
    ),
    # color='cpr:Q',
    # tooltip=tooltip
)

text = base.mark_text(
    baseline='middle',
    dx=0,

).encode(
    text='cpr',
    tooltip=[]
)

chart = alt.layer(base + heatmap + text).facet(
    'GEN5_RISK_BAND_CALC:N', 
    columns=2
)

chart

# %%
```

I get this:

[image: What I get]

Comment: tutorial in link use `heatmap + text` but you have `base + heatmap + text` - what you get when you remove `base`? Maybe `base` draws another text and this makes all blurry/duplicated

Comment: as for me it looks like you have too many data. You create random values and many values are assigned to the same cell in heatmap - so probably it plots all values. I don't know `Altair` but maybe you need some `count` of all values

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple `cpr` values for each combination of the encodings in your chart, so all of them are plotted on top of each other. If you want to plot a single value, you will need to tell altair how to aggregate it, e.g. `text='mean(cpr)'`